# MySql Insert ON Duplicate Key with a select not working

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I use a select for the on duplicate key update part inside an insert?

I thought this would, but it does not. The select part works fine on its own, however.

```
insert into tags (tag) values ('sony') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = (
    select count(*) from items where FIND_IN_SET(tag, tags)
) WHERE tag IN ('sony');
```

**items**

```
"id"    "tags"                  "category"
"1"     "sony,pioneer,philips"  "1"
"2"     "sony,pioneer"          "1"
"3"     "sony"                  "1"
"4"     "bose,sony"             "1"
"5"     "bose"                  "1"
"6"     "bose"                  "1"
```

**tags**

```
"id"    "tag"       "total" "category"
"1"     "sony"      "0"     "1"
"2"     "pioneer"   "0"     "1"
"3"     "philips"   "0"     "1"
"4"     "bose"      "0"     "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the parentheses:

```
insert into tags(tag)
    values ('sony')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = (select count(*)
                                     from items
                                     where FIND_IN_SET(tag, tags) and
                                           tag IN ('sony')
                                     );
```

The `where` clause at the end should be causing a syntax error.

EDIT:

If you want the value from the `insert`, you can try:

```
insert into tags(tag)
    values ('sony')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = (select count(*)
                                     from items
                                     where FIND_IN_SET(VALUES(tag), tags) 
                                    );
```

I have not tried this in a subquery, but `VALUES()` does work in expressions.

Comment: Why do I keep getting `Unknown column 'tag' in 'where clause `

Comment: @Norman . . . Presumably because `tag` is not in the `items` table.  You don't specify the data layout of your tables, only the non-working query, so there is no way to know where a given value is.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tags (tag)
  VALUES ('sony')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  total = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM items
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('sony', tags)
  )
```

Condition `tag IN ('sony')` is not required, because `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` updates row, where `tag = 'sony'` - as this row reports duplicate.

Comment: Did you change this answer cause now I get `Unknown column 'tag' in 'where clause`

Comment: @Norman You are right, here need duplicate `'sony'` value - corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a subquery as expression in an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement. (If that's valid, then pattern in the answer from Rimas, or in the second example from Gordon, would be what you'd want.)

---

I find it odd that a value is assigned to the `total` column only in the UPDATE action and not the INSERT action.

Personally, I'd prefer to have a value assigned to the `total` column on the INSERT as well. I would do something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO tags (tag,total)
SELECT 'sony', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items i WHERE FIND_IN_SET('sony',i.tags))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = VALUES(total)
```